# context switch between two processes in linux

Tags: c, linux

i am writing a program that sumulates a terminal, i wrote another dummy progra which only takes input and print it out. the dummy prog:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char text[128] = {0};
while(1){
    fgets (text, 128, stdin);
    printf("%s\n", text);
}
return 0;
}
```

in my main program i run the dummy program with fork->exec. my question is which one of them gets the input from the user? is there context switch between them so one process takes the input at a time or the father process will take all the input unless i call wait.

EDIT: The input will not be shared.

then i want to call the child process to the foreground i try to use tcsetpgrp but with no success. i do the following:

```
if((son = fork())==0){//son process
}else{//father
printf("the old group id is:%d\n", getpgid(son));
setpgid(son,son);
k = printf("the new group id is:%d\n",getpgid(son));
j = tcgetpgrp(0, getpgid(son))
}
```

j is set to 25 for some reason and both the pgid before the setpgrp and after is the same.

Comment: You should *read the manual* for `fork` and `exec` and figure out yourself what happens to open file descriptors such as the standard input.

Comment: hello there, my problem is not with the fork exec but with preventing and allowing input for the new process

Comment: Your question is ultimately about what happens to the standard input. This is documented as part of the behaviour of both `fork` and `exec`.

Answer (score 1):

The main program is connected to the terminal and gets the input. If you use threading instead of creating a fork, the I/O will be shared between the threads.

If only one thread reads, it gets all the input. If two or more threads read, they do not share the data, and the outcome is kindof unpredictable.